# How to only allow the pupil edit his/her activities?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9

So I got a module where the user have activities. The problem is that everyone can edit them. I want to make that only the pupil registered on the activity to edit it.
[View of teh activity from odoo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oArgc.png)

Models.py class

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api, exceptions

class Activity(models.Model):
    _name = "proyectosge.activity"

    date = fields.Date(default=fields.Date.today)
    description = fields.Char(required=True)
    duration = fields.Float(digits=(2,1), help="Duration in hours")
    remarks = fields.Text(required=True)

    owner = fields.Many2one('res.users', string="Pupil",default=lambda self: self.env.user,readonly=True)


    @api.constrains('duration')
    def _check_duration_not_too_long(self):
        for r in self:
            if r.duration > 8:
                raise exceptions.ValidationError("A activity can´t be more than 8 hours")

    @api.constrains('duration')
    def _check_duration_not_too_short(self):
        for r in self:
            if r.duration < 0:
                raise exceptions.ValidationError("A activity can´t be less than 0 hours ")
```

Also want that other user could read on other pupil activities

Comment: don't put photo of your code, put the real code in text.

Comment: YEah will take that in count for next one. Ty btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User ir.rule

```xml
   <record model="ir.rule" id="activities_rule">
        <field name="name">User is allowed to update his activities</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_proyectosge_activity"/>
        <!--
            the user is allowed to update or delete the activities that belong
            to him.
          -->
        <field name="domain_force">[('owner','=',user.id)]</field>
         <field name="perm_read" eval="Flase"/>
        <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
        <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>
        <field name="perm_unlink" eval="True"/>
    </record>
```